# Sorting and Updating a Generic List of Object based on a Sub Object

Tags: c#

I have the following objects:

```
public class TestResult
    {
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }

        public int MaxSectionScore { get; set; }

        public bool IsPartialScore { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfAttempts { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestResultGroup
    {
        public TestResultGroup()
        {
            Results = new List<TestResult>();
            Sections = new List<string>();
        }
        public List<TestResult> Results { get; set; }
        public List<string> Sections { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
```

So, a TestResultGroup can have any number of results of type TestResult. These test results only differ by their SectionName.

I have a `List<TestResultGroup>` which I need to sort into descending order based on a score in the `Results` property, but only when `Results` has an item whos `SectionName` = "MeanScore" (if it doesnt have this section we can assume a score of -1). How would I go about ordering the list? Ideally I would also like to apply the result of this ordering to the `Rank` property.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
List<TestResultGroup> groups = ...

// group test result groups by the same score and sort
var sameScoreGroups = groups.GroupBy(
    gr =>
    {
        var meanResult = gr.Results.FirstOrDefault(res => res.SectionName == "MeanScore");
        return meanResult != null ? meanResult.Score : -1;
    })
    .OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Key);

int rank = 1;
foreach (var sameScoreGroup in sameScoreGroups)
{
   foreach (var group in sameScoreGroup)
   {
      group.Rank = rank;
   }
   rank++;
}

// to obtain sorted groups:
var sortedGroups = groups.OrderByDescending(gr => gr.Rank).ToArray();
```

Or even write one expression with a side effect:

```
List<TestResultGroup> groups = ...
int rank = 1; 
var sortedGroups = groups
    .GroupBy(
        gr =>
        {
            var meanResult = gr.Results.FirstOrDefault(res => res.SectionName == "MeanScore");
            return meanResult != null ? meanResult.Score : -1;
    })
    .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Key)
    .SelectMany(grouping =>
        {
            int groupRank = rank++;
            foreach (var group in grouping)
            {
                group.Rank = groupRank;
            }
            return grouping;
        })
     .ToArray(); // or ToList
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using 6? It wouldnt be my call to upgrade the project

Comment: I removed null propagation operator from my solution, so it does not require C# 6.0

Comment: Many thanks, your sorting worked like a charm, the ranking sadly not. I probably wasnt clear enough, if 2 results have the same mean score, then they should have the same rank